# io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException is received

Tags: jsonschema, rest-assured

I am trying to validate the JSON schema for Places to Search google API using Rest Assured 3.10 and receiving io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') error.

I have validated the schema using online JSON Schema validator and there seems to be no issue.

### Below is the code:

```java
public void validateJSONSchema() {
    RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com/";

given().
    queryParam("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
    queryParam("radius","1500").
    queryParam("type","restaurant").
    queryParam("keyword","cruise").
    queryParam("key",<API Key>).
    when().
    get("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
    then().assertThat().statusCode(200).contentType(ContentType.JSON).
    body(matchesJsonSchema("src\\main\\resources\\googleAPIs\\json\\placesearch.json"));

}
```

---

### I am receiving below error:

```
FAILED: validateJSONSchema
io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@21526f6c; line: 1, column: 2]
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:286)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:107)
    at googleapis.FindaPlaceTest.validateJSONSchema(FindaPlaceTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@21526f6c; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:532)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:453)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1386)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:669)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.hasNextValue(MappingIterator.java:159)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.readNode(JsonNodeReader.java:142)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonNodeReader.fromReader(JsonNodeReader.java:127)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.fromReader(JsonLoader.java:179)
    at com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.fromString(JsonLoader.java:192)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$1.createSchemaInstance(JsonSchemaValidator.java:105)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$1.createSchemaInstance(JsonSchemaValidator.java:102)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:284)
    ... 26 more
```

---

### JSON Schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "candidates": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "formatted_address": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "location": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "lat": {
                                            "type": "number"
                                        },
                                        "lng": {
                                            "type": "number"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "lat",
                                        "lng"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "viewport": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "northeast": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "lat": {
                                                    "type": "number"
                                                },
                                                "lng": {
                                                    "type": "number"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "lat",
                                                "lng"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "southwest": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "lat": {
                                                    "type": "number"
                                                },
                                                "lng": {
                                                    "type": "number"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "lat",
                                                "lng"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "northeast",
                                        "southwest"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "location",
                                "viewport"
                            ]
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "opening_hours": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "open_now": {
                                    "type": "boolean"
                                },
                                "weekday_text": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "open_now",
                                "weekday_text"
                            ]
                        },
                        "photos": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "height": {
                                            "type": "integer"
                                        },
                                        "html_attributions": {
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "items": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "photo_reference": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "width": {
                                            "type": "integer"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "height",
                                        "html_attributions",
                                        "photo_reference",
                                        "width"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "rating": {
                            "type": "number"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "formatted_address",
                        "geometry",
                        "name",
                        "opening_hours",
                        "photos",
                        "rating"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "debug_log": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "line": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "line"
            ]
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "candidates",
        "debug_log",
        "status"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what your response is? Maybe it isn't JSON.

Comment: The response is JSON actually and the assertion in the code for Content type JSON is also returning true.

Comment: In which case, please provide your JSON data. It looks like the schema is valid, so that only leaves the data.

Comment: After a little googling, it looks like the function `matchesJsonSchema` is expecting a JSON object, hence the error unexpected `s`. "s" is the first character of that string. What documentation did you use to believe you could reference the JSON Schema file in that way?

Comment: I was able to figure out the error. It was the way I was passing the file name in the JSONSchemaValidator method. 
Thank you everyone for support.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
String expectedJson = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/test/resources/uploads/mobilesdk.json"));
    response.then().assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchema(expectedJson));
```

Try reading your json to string and then assert it .